# how can I insert each array value as a separate row in Php and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to take the array `$_POST['custom']` and insert the values into separate rows in a mysql database.

`var_dump($_POST['custom'])` gives the array `array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "item1, item2, " }`,

I've tried foreach and echo to see if I can produce the lines individually, but I just get the entire array returned:

```
$array = $_POST['custom'];

foreach ($array as $item)
{
    echo $item,'-';
}
```

and the output is `item1, item2, -` instead of being `item1-item2`

what I'm trying to do is insert each item into a separate row, along with the user_id that purchased the item - for example:

```
user_id  |  item
-----------------
user_1   | item1
user_1   | item2
```

I can insert into a single row by using `json_encode($_POST['custom'])` and then your standard insert query even though the formatting is a bit strange with the quotes and [] (I've tried both implode and explode they don't work - but I can live with that for now). That table looks like

```
user_id  |  item
-----------------
user_1   | ["item1,item2,"]
```

My main issue is how to get the array of values `item1`,`item2`,`etc` to be used as a individual value to insert data into a single row per item so that it looks like the first table above.

**EDIT**

Html form

```
<form name="paypalCheckout" action="<?php echo PPCART_URL; ?>" method="post">

            <input type="HIDDEN" name="business" value="<?php echo PPCART_ACCOUNT; ?>">
            <input type="HIDDEN" name="cmd" value="_cart">
            <input type="HIDDEN" name="upload" value="1">
            <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="<?php echo PPCART_CURRENCY; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="<?php echo PPCART_COUNTRY; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo PPCART_RETURN_URL; ?>">   
            <?php
            if (isset ($_SESSION['paypalCart']))
            {
                foreach($_SESSION['paypalCart'] as $product)
                    {
                    $custom .= $product['name'].",";


                    }
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom?>">
           //<input type="hidden" name="custom[]" value="<?php echo $custom?>"> I have also tried this
```

the relevant part is the `$custom` variable - it is initialized already as `$custom="";`

**Solution**

```
                    <?php
            if (isset ($_SESSION['paypalCart']))
            {
                foreach($_SESSION['paypalCart'] as $product)
                    {
                    $custom .= $product['name'].",";


                    }
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $custom?>">
```

then in the processing php file I have

```
$db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);


$user_id = "Test";
$custom = $_POST['custom'];
//print_r($_POST['custom']); This is good to see what your array looks like before it gets trimmed

$trim = rtrim($custom, ",");
$explode = explode(',',$trim);
//print_r($_POST['custom']); Good way to check what it looks like after being trimmed to make sure you have trimmed it correctly.

foreach ($explode as $course_id)
{
    $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO `subscriptions`(`user_id`, `course_id`) VALUES ('".$user_id."','".$course_id."')");

    if($sql)
    {
     echo "it's good";

    }
    else
    echo "no good", mysql_error();

}
```

Comment: show us your html form or take a look at "explode"

Comment: could you please show the output of print_r($_POST['custom'])

Comment: @Malkocoglu print_r gives me `Array ( [0] => item1,item2, )`

Comment: @mightyuhu I have updated it with the html form, and as I mentioned above neither implode nor explode work. I get the error `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in` or `Array to string conversion in` `Array` and I used both `","` and `','` with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is:

```
[0] => "item1, item2, "
```

and not:

```
[0] => "item1",
[1] => "item2"
```

You have to `explode` your values first by comma, if it's an appropriate separator (and `trim` them afterwards).

Comment: I've updated the post with my html form, I'm not sure what I need to change to get it the way you have. Also I get the error `explode() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in` or `Array to string conversion in` `Array` and I used both `","` and `','` with no luck

Comment: @Fahad If you want to work as you expect, so, you have to repeat the custom input in your form. Otherwise, this answer is perfect.

Comment: @sємsєм what do you mean? How would I do that?

Comment: @Fahad look at the last line of the code you regarded, remove the comment and make the the line before it is the same as it. i.e. the name attribute should be custom[] in both input fields.

Comment: I got it, thanks. the problem was that I had a space after the comma, so when I would explode it wouldn't read it properly, after I removed that extra space it worked fine

Comment: You can use array_filter to clean resulting arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Before storing the array in the database use

```
$item = serialize($_POST["custom"]);
```

Now you are ready to store it in DB. When you retrieve the field value this time unserialize it:

```
$custom_array = unserialize($item);
```

Here you go, your array is just like you stored it in the DB.

Comment: Self comment: this is not your answer I think :) Just another hack like you already do...